# Apache response time is severly impacted by KeepAlive timeout value

Tags: apache

When I enabled KeepAlive on my server, response times of all my php pages (measured using browser tools) are now nearly equal to the timeout value specified in the KeepAlive settings.

Foe example, the following settings:

```
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 30
```

will lead to response times of 30 seconds for every page!

I know KeepAlive and response time should not be related, but I do not know how to explain this.
any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I was behind a new corporate proxy that day...that that changes everything.
I am leaving this question here in case somebody else hits the same rock

Answer (score 0):

I am sure it's a myth. But one of the thing which you need to look if there are any ajax calls being called recursively which might make you feel of same response time.